# How to detect page refresh in .net core angular SPA template?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, angular6, single-page-application

I have project setup with .net core MVC SPA template. When the application is loaded, it loads angular spa into MVC.

My startup configure has below code to load SPA.

```
        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
```

Once the SPA is loaded, there is no contact with server side on the MVC site. However when the page is reloaded, I would like to intercept this call and do something with the HTTPRequest and HTTPResponse. How do I achieve this ? I do not have any controller in the MVC project.

My project structure looks like this.

WEB 
 - wwwroot 
 - ClientApp      ---> Angular spa 
 - Controllers    ---> Empty 
 - Pages          ---> Empty 
 - startup.cs 
 - program.cs

Comment: Can I ask what you're trying to achieve? Why do you need to detect page reload?

Comment: We need to refresh some of the CSS when page loads. This css will be designed by external tool so we would like to setup this css when the page loads and then SPA can take over and render style as is. If css changed on server then on page load we can again put new css

Comment: What do you mean by `when the page is reloaded`? By pressing `F5`?

Answer (score 1):

For intercepting the request between client and server, you could try [ASP.NET Core Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.1). All the requests from client will be handled by `middleware`.

A simple code like below:

```
        app.Use((context, next) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(context.Request.Path);
            return next.Invoke();
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
```

**Update**

```
            app.Map("/css/site1.css", map => {
            map.Run(context => {
                context.Response.Redirect("/css/site2.css");
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            });
        });
```

Comment: I am able to intercept this way but can I insert CSS through app.use() { } inside the angular page ?

Comment: @Zeus What do you mean by insert css? if you want to change the css url, you could try [URL Rewriting Middleware in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-2.1), but it is not recommended which will cause performance. You should change the css url in the page instead of intercept the reuqest.

Comment: There is a requirement to update css on demand i.e. whitelabel